# Web service cannot write to Event Log when called by anonymous user

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, logging

SUMMARY: How to configure a web service such that writing to the Event Log is always possible (regardless of caller)? 
DETAILS:
I have a web service which writes an entry to the Application Log. I established the event source for this by means of a little console application and I think I understand that part of things. When I test this WS, I see I am successfully writing my entry to the Event log.

The virtual directory which hosts this WS does **NOT** allow anonymous access and is configured for Integrated Windows Auth only.

I have a web client application that calls this Webservice. When the web client site is configured for Integrated Windows Auth only, calls to the Webservice result in logging as desired.

Yet, if I change the web client site to allow anonymous access then the Webservice attempt to log results in an InvalidOperationException. I ignore it but it would be nice to know how to get logging in the webservice regardless of how it is called. Here is a bit of my code:

```
   public FileService()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(g_EventSource))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(g_EventSource, g_EventLog);

            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity UserIdentityInfo;
            UserIdentityInfo = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            string AuthType = UserIdentityInfo.AuthenticationType;

    if (AuthType == "Kerberos")
    { engineWSE.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; }
    else
    { engineWSE.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("u", "p", "domain"); }

    EventLog.WriteEntry(g_EventSource,
                "Caller: " + UserIdentityInfo.Name +
                " AuthType: " + UserIdentityInfo.AuthenticationType,
                EventLogEntryType.Information, 1);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            // do nothing to ignore: "Cannot open log for source 'myAppSourceName'. You may not have write access." 
        }
    }
```

The example in the constructor above is sort of contrived for here (I am mainly interested in being able to write out info related to errors in the web service).

I hope there is a way to configure the web service virtual directory (or the code within) so that logging is possible regardless of how it got called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also check your web.config.

If IIS is set to anonymous and web.config is set to windows / impersonate. Then it will be the anonymous IIS user that is trying to write to the event log.

Comment: Thanks. I re-read my question closely per your answer. I do indeed have <identity impersonate="true"/> and <authentication mode="Windows" /> in the web.config of the website hosting my webservice. I need this because I need the identity of the INTRAnet webclient (see how I test the authentication type and pass credentials accordingly). So, are you saying that because of "impersonate" in the web.config, it is behaving as if I had checked "Anonymous access" for my webservice site? I think you're going to say yes. Given my objectives, is there anyway to configure this for logging in any case?

Comment: You need to give the IIS anonymous user the right to write to the event log. It's name is IUSR....

Comment: I know how to set permissions on files or folders for IUSR_SERVERNAME but how to give that account the right to write to event log?

Comment: It requires an editing of the registry see: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericfitz/archive/2006/03/01/541462.aspx
for details.

Comment: Thanks to you, I found these details below at this link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301309

Set the following Registry key to 0 instead of 1, and then restart your computer for the changes to take effect.
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application
Name: RestrictGuestAccess
Type: REG_DWORD
NOTE: This enables all Guest accounts to write to the Application Event Log.

Answer (score 3):

Network Service is allowed [to *write* to the Event Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998320.aspx#paght000015_eventlogaccess), but not create an event source. you could give permissions to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\` to allow it to create - but if you've already created it at install time, there's no need.

It's possible that it's failing on the `SourceExists` as well - since that requires enumerating the same registry key. I'd probably just remove the SourceExists/Create check and trust that it's there - if you're anonymous, you can't create it anyway.